# White solder pads on through-hole PCB

Tags: pcb, soldering

They look like covers at first glance but they aren't stickered on. I've never seen pads like this and searching doesn't bring up any results. Any information on these?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a PCB finish, called Immersion Silver, or IS for short.

Some other common types of finishes:

- Hot air-levelled solder (HASL) - Just your normal solder, levelled with hot air knives.
- Electroless Nickel Immersion Gold (ENIG) - Your typical matte gold.
- Galvanic Gold - Different type of gold finish, looks shiny and polished.
- Organic Solderability Preservative (OSP) - Looks like bare copper.

Comment: AFAIK galvanic gold is actually galvanic nickel-gold, you still need a diffusion barrier just as with ENIG.